# How to get the last visible child table row of a html table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to know how to get the last visible child of an HTML table using jQuery? The reason I ask is, I cannot use CSS 3 to get the last child because older browsers do not support it and this is kind of a legacy projects I am working on.

I have a table structure like this:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Some name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td>Some name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The last table row is not visible and it gets shown when clicking on a plus sign next to the data but it is not relevant. I want to find out how to get the last visible table row using jQuery selectors.

Currently I am using

```
$last = $('#table').find('tbody tr:last-child');
$last.addClass('last-child');
```

But its actually returning the hidden table row.

Thank you in advance

Comment: is it this your looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241554/how-to-add-some-custom-css-for-the-last-child-only-if-visible-with-jquery

Comment: since visibility is defined through css and can be inherited, i'd use .height() or .width() (some physical property of any kind). i'd start from the last element and go up to the first (until i reach one with physical property). oh i see it's done in jquery visible selector - http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: [css-selectors] is not a tag for jQuery selector questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
$('tr:visible:last','#table')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$last = $('tbody tr:visible').last();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$last = $('#table').find('tbody tr:visible:last');
$last.addClass('last-child');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ptGE2/

As Mathieu linked to.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these

```
$last = $('#table').find('tbody tr:visible:last-child');

or

$last = $('#table').find('tbody tr:visible').is(':last-child');
```